# Test if a remote file (different domain) can be accessed

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, cors

Our site uses mp3 files a lot, loaded remotely within various resources on our site.  Users of our site (usually in schools) often have problems with local networks blocking mp3s.  I'm trying to set up some jquery code to test whether we can load a list of external mp3 files ok.

It works when i request a file from the same domain as I'm testing, but not if I request it from any of our asset servers, which are called (for the sake of argument)

```
assets0.example.com
assets1.example.com
assets2.example.com
assets3.example.com
```

My code is:

```
url = "http://assets0.example.com/path/to/an.mp3"
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "get",
  success: function(request, status){
    console.log("success.");
  }, 
  error: function(request, status, error){
    console.log("ERROR: request = ",request);
  }
});
```

What's weird is when I call this, I can see, in the dev sidebar, that the request has a 200 status, but has 0 bytes size.  My code runs the `error` block.

If I change the url to `"/path/to/an.mp3"`, so it's using the local version, it works fine.

I don't actually need to do anything with the mp3, so downloading zero bytes of it is actually fine.  I just need to see whether I'm allowed to get it, if you know what I mean.

CORS is enabled on the server that I'm trying to get it from.  I've tried various options.  The closest I've got to something that actually works is passing

dataType: "JSONP",

in the options.  This then loads the entire file in, but then has a syntax error trying to process it (presumably because it's trying to parse it as json?).

I'd prefer to avoid loading the whole file down, if possible, like I say:  I just need to test whether i can access it ok.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this?

EDIT:  these are the header I see (doing a 'HEAD' request rather than a 'GET'):

```
REQUEST HEADERS:
Host: assets0.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://local.dev/
Origin: http://local.dev
Connection: keep-alive

RESPONSE HEADERS:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2874138
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 15:23:36 GMT
Etag: "507687da-2bdb1a"
Expires: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 16:23:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 08:48:26 GMT
Server: nginx
```

Comment: Does the console have anything else to say? Have you checked in network panel whether the response headers relevant to CORS are _actually_ present?

Comment: You should make this a HEAD request rather than a GET eventually; that you don’t get the actual content of the mp3 file right now seems to be by accident, but with a regular, “working” GET request you would.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've got the args returned in my error block, but can't seem to interrogate any useful information out of them.  Do you have any suggestions?  thanks

Comment: @CBroe which headers do you mean, specifically?  I can see the response headers but don't know what i'm looking for.  I've changed it to a HEAD request btw.

Comment: At least `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be present, if CORS is supposed to work.

Comment: @CBroe it's not there.  I've edited my question to include both sets of headers.  cheers

Comment: Then you should get a message in browser console saying that this cross-domain request failed, because there were no CORS headers ... _"CORS is enabled on the server that I'm trying to get it from"_ - looks like you need to re-check on that.